# Issue with using fetch in JS

Tags: javascript, fetch, addeventlistener

Here's the code:

```
        but.addEventListener("click", () => {
        fetch("employees.json")
            .then(resp => {

                if (res.status >= 400) {
                    return Promise.reject();
                }
                console.log(resp);

                return resp.json();
                // const a = resp.json();
                // for (const worker of a) {
                //         const employee = AddDOMWorker(worker);
                //         res.appendChild(employee);
                //     }

            })
            .then(
                (emps) => {
                    for (const worker of emps) {
                        const employee = AddDOMWorker(worker);
                        res.appendChild(employee);
                    }
                }
            )
    });

    function AddDOMWorker(employee) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("friend");
        div.textContent = `${employee.id} ${employee.position}`;
        return div;
    }
```

Why I should use ***.then*** after returning resp.json(). Why can't I just put resp.json() in *a* variable and get rid of the second **.then** (commented code)?

Comment: Because `resp.json()` returns a promise.

Comment: What happens when you try?  Testing and observing is always more informative than asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resp.json()` returns a `Promise`, so you need to chain another `.then()` method call. Returning `resp.json()` from the callback function makes sure that the `Promise` returned by the wrapper `then()` method gets resolved to the promise returned by `resp.json()`.

The `Promise` returned by the first `then()` method will either be rejected or fulfilled depending on what happens to the `Promise` returned by `resp.json()`. Callback function of the second `then()` method call is executed when the promise returned by the first `then()` method is fulfilled.

If you use `async-await` syntax, then you will need to `await` `resp.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `json()`, like all [response methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#body_interface_methods), [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

As such, like all promises, it is asynchronous, and must be either `await`ed, or used with a chained `then()` callback.